# PYTHON code Take a range, and print all the numbers skipping multiple of 10, and also if the range is higher than 100 it will print only upto 100

Tags: python, loops

## Can anyone help me with this?

x = int(input("Enter a number"))

```
for i in range(1, x):

    if i % 10 == 0:

    continue

        print(i)

while x > 100:

break
```

''' I know this is a very silly problem, but I am a beginner. I coded upto this, but i am facing a problem while printing within the Range 100'''

Comment: Identation in your code is unclear. But I think this is breaking `for` loop: `while x > 100:
break`

Comment: Indent your code, it is not reproductible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking each number is greater than 100 or not. You can change `range()` to limit max number below 100 using `min(100, x)` will return 100 if x is greater than 100 else return x.

```
x = int(input())
for num in range(1, min(100, x)):
    if num % 10 != 0:
        print(num)
```

Comment: min(x, y) returns the minimum between x and y. For instance if x = 2, min(100, x) will return 2 as 2 is less than 100 ; if x = 150 it will return 100 as 100 is less than 150. min(100, x) will always return x if x is less than 100, and will return 100 for x greater than 100.